# GLSL Pseudo Random in Range

Tags: random, parallel-processing, range, glsl, compute-shader

I need to generate a pseudo random number, in specified range, using glsl

Something like this

```
float rand(vec2 co)
{
   return fract(sin(dot(co.xy,vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453);
}
```

or this

```
highp float rand(vec2 co)
{
    highp float a = 12.9898;
    highp float b = 78.233;
    highp float c = 43758.5453;
    highp float dt= dot(co.xy ,vec2(a,b));
    highp float sn= mod(dt,3.14);
    return fract(sin(sn) * c);
}
```

both from [here](https://thebookofshaders.com/10/) and [here](http://byteblacksmith.com/improvements-to-the-canonical-one-liner-glsl-rand-for-opengl-es-2-0/) respectively, would probably work, but I need to be able to specify a range (ie 1-10) for each pseudo random number.

In addition, I am using a glsl compute shader, not a vertex shader, so I do not have access to the typical vertex shader variables such as `st`

Comment: *"so I do not have access to the typical vertex shader variables such as st"* - `st` access the components of a vector. See [Swizzling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Swizzling)

Comment: Both functions create a random values in range [0.0, 1.0]. You can map this to a range [a, b] with _a + (b-a) * x_ or `mix(a, b, x)`